# Replace string.Split with other constructs - Optimization

Tags: c#, string, optimization, compiler-optimization, string-search

Here I am using `Split` function to get the parts of string.

```
string[] OrSets = SubLogic.Split('|');
foreach (string OrSet in OrSets)
{
  bool OrSetFinalResult = false;
    if (OrSet.Contains('&'))
    {
        OrSetFinalResult = true;
        if (OrSet.Contains('0'))
        {
            OrSetFinalResult = false;
        }
        //string[] AndSets = OrSet.Split('&');
        //foreach (string AndSet in AndSets)
        //{
        //    if (AndSet == "0")
        //    {
        //        // A single "false" statement makes the entire And statement FALSE
        //        OrSetFinalResult = false;
        //        break;
        //    }
        //}

    }
    else
    {
        if (OrSet == "1")
        {
            OrSetFinalResult = true;
        }
    }

    if (OrSetFinalResult)
    {
        // A single "true" statement makes the entire OR statement TRUE
        FinalResult = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I replace the `Split` operation , along with replacement of `foreach` constructs.

Comment: What do you mean by "other constructs"? With what you want to replace the functions and why?

Comment: Why do you want to optimize that? Is this really a bottleneck in your program?

Comment: your question is not clear. Please elaborate it.

Comment: @Etienne de Martel  : yes ..it seems to be like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hypothesis #1

Depending of the kind of your process, you can parallellize the work :

```
var OrSets = SubLogic.Split('|').AsParallel();
foreach (string OrSet in OrSets)
{
  ...
  ....
}
```

However, this can often leads to problems with multithreaded apps (locking resource, etc.).
And you have also to measure the benefits. Switching from one thread to another can be costly. If the job is small, the AsParallel will be slower than a simple sequential loop.

This is very efficient when you have latency with network resource, or any kind of I/O.

#### Hypothesis #2

Your SubLogic variable is very very very big

You can, in this case, walk sequentially the file :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var SubLogic = "darere|gfgfgg|gfgfg";

        using (var sr = new StringReader(SubLogic))
        {

            var str = string.Empty;
            int charValue;
            do
            {
                charValue = sr.Read();
                var c = (char)charValue;
                if (c == '|' || (charValue == -1 && str.Length > 0))
                {
                    Process(str);
                    str = string.Empty; // Reset the string
                }
                else
                {
                    str += c;
                }
            } while (charValue >= 0);

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Process(string str)
    {
        // Your actual Job
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

Also, depending of the length of each chunk between `|`, you may want to use a StringBuilder and not a simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that if you need to optimize to improve the performance of your application, that the code *inside* of the foreach loop is what needs to be optimized, not the string.Split method.

*[EDIT:]*

There are a number of good answers elsewhere on StackOverflow related to optimized string parsing:

- [Fastest Way to Parse Large Strings (multi threaded)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114604/241754)
- [Fast string parsing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3157895/241754)

String.Split() likely does more than you can do on your own to actually split the string up in a well-optimized manner. That assumes that you are interesting in returning true or false for each split section of your input, of course. Otherwise, you can just focus on searching your string.

As others have mentioned, if you need to search through a huge string (many hundreds of megabytes) and, especially, do so repeatedly and continuously, then look at what .NET 4 gives you with the [Task Parallel Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx).

For searching through strings, you can look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228630.aspx) on MSDN for how to use  IndexOf, LastIndexOf, StartsWith, and EndsWith methods. Those should perform better than the Contains method.

Of course, the best solution is dependent upon the facts of your particular situation. You'll want to use the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to see how long your implementations (both current and new) take to see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly deal with it by using `StringBuilder`. 
Try reading char-by-char from your source string into `StringBuilder`, till you find '|', then process what a `StringBuilder` contains. 
That is how you'll avoid creation of tonns of `String` objects and save a lot of memory.

If you would have used Java, I'd recommend using `StringTokenizer` and `StreamTokenizer` classes. It's a pity there are no similar classes in .NET